# Multi level user login and session

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I have a problem with multi-level user login in PHP MySQL. I already have a code but the user still can access the admin site, what's the problem with my code? still, I do have a problem with the session of admin and user acct. thank you! here's my code.

```
require('db.php');
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['username'])){

    $account = stripslashes($_REQUEST['account']); 
    $account = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$account);

    $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); //escapes special 
    characters in a string

    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);



//Checking is user existing in the database or not
   $query = "SELECT * FROM users_detail WHERE account = '$account',username= 
            '$username' and password= '$password' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($account == "admin" && $rows['username'] = $username && 
   $rows['password']=$password){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
        }

    if($account == "user" && $rows['username'] = $username && 
      $rows['password']=$password){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        header("Location: add user.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
        }else{


            echo " <div class='alert'>
                        Username/password is incorrect. Click <a href = 'login.php'>here</a> to log-in.
                </div> ";

        }
}else{
?>`
```

Comment: Within your `if` condition you are using assignment operator *=*, Not sure if you are intentionally doing this, It should be an comparison operation *==*

Comment: User passwords should ***NEVER*** be stored in plain text form, they should ***ALWAYS*** be hashed!!!!! Also you should be using prepared statements as they are a fair bit safer than mysqli_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the full solution,

**1 , in your user table you need to create a column call user_role
every user in the table either admin or normal_user**

[image]

**2 in your log.php , first fetch data base get the user_role value , when you verify user password and db password , save as session .**

```
<?php 

      if( isset($_POST['login_btn'])){  // someone click login btn

    $username = clean($_POST['username']); 
    //clean is the custom function to remove all harmful code
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);


    // run query to get db username & password i am using prepare stmt for more secure , you can use mysqli_fetch_array , but need to implement mysql_real_escape_string for sql injection

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT username,password,email,user_role FROM your table WHERE username = ? ");

    //$connection is your db connection 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $bind_username,$bind_password,$bind_email,$bind_user_role);

    confirm($stmt); // confirm is also custom function to check query is successful execute
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        $db_username = $bind_username;;
        $db_password = $bind_password ;
        $db_email    = $bind_email ;
        $user_role   = $bind_user_role ;
    }

    //  do form validation           
    if($username =="" or $password =="" ){
        echo 'All Fileds Are Required'; 
    }elseif( $username !== $db_username ){
        echo 'username not existed';
    }else{
    if( password_verify($password, $db_password)){
    // assuming your using password_hash function to verify , or you can just use simply compare $password == db_password                                           
    // if password_verify return true meaning correct password then save all necessary sessions
    $_SESSION['username']         = $db_username ;
    $_SESSION['user_email']       = $db_email ;
    $_SESSION['user_role']        = $user_role ;

    // first method ->    header('Location: portal.php');      
    // you can now direct to portal page{1st method } where all admin or normal user can view 
    // or you can now do separate redirection (2nd method below )
    // remember $user_role  will == 'admin' or 'normal_user'
if( $user_role == 'admin' ){
    header('Location: page_admin_will_view.php');
}elseif(  $user_role == 'normal_user'  ){
    header('Location: page_normal_user_will_view.php');
}

    }else{
       echo 'incorrect password';
    }

 }                                  
    }  //  end of post request 

?>
```

**3 how about normal user accidentally visit the admin page ? 
we have consider this and do some extra work
put below code in the page_admin_will_view.php header**

```
<?php 
    if( isset($_SESSION['user_role'] )){ 
    // meaning user is logged in 
        if(  $_SESSION['user_role']  !== 'admin'){
        // meaning user_role is not amind , redirect to the page normal user belongs to
         header("Location: ../normal_users.php");
    }

    } else{
        //redirect to somewhere meaning user is not logged in
         header("Location: ../somewhere.php");
    }

?>
```

I hope this would help you , and I am using it, it may not be a perfect solution. but it works for me. hah

Comment: in your html form, do you include the user_role?

Comment: mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username); what is "s"? and whats your db name and table name?

Comment: s stands for string , here are the reference 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
you can create whatever db name and table name.

Comment: i already copied your code, no error, but its not redirecting in the said location. no action.

Comment: did you login successfully ? can you share your code , so that we can check thanks

Comment: Sure. I can zip my files to you, haha. but where can I share my code to you?

Comment: u can email to admin@anthonydemo.net.  thank you , by the way , you are in Philippines right ? perhaps we can meet lol

Comment: @Rchl Sy i had replied your email pls check thank you

Comment: what should i do if i got Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function clean()

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_num_rows($result)` returns the number of rows. 
So after `$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);` you need to write fetch data using `mysqli_fetch_array($query)`

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array($query) if i put this to my code, do i need to add another variable for it?

Comment: Yes fetch the value in a variable & just print_r() it.you will get the clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is RBAC(Role Base Access Control).

```
if($account == "admin" && $rows['username'] = $username && $rows['password']=$password){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['access'] = $account;
}
```

And on your pages where you want admin access, probably you should either redirect the user to home or send an UnAuthorised access message.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['access']) && $_SESSION['access'] != 'admin') {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Also if you are looking for more controlling based on the role I will suggest you to use a library like 
http://phprbac.net/

Comment: the code you gave to me can still access the user to the admin site. </3

Comment: Can you paste the content of index.php after the change you made as per my solution.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/A/B/C/FINAL/ADMIN/login.php on line 59

Comment: That might be because you have an error in your query and hence your function is returning false. 

Try this `mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('Error in query')` to confirm if your query have no errors

Answer (score 0):

first of all , create admin role like you did with $account 
 when user login save their admin_role in session ,

```
$admin_user = $_SESSION['admin_user'] ;
$normal_user = $_SESSION['normal_user'] ;
```

in admin site , like admin.php , the page you do not want normal user view 
write this {perfectly write it in header.php}

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){  
//meaning user is logged in
    if(isset($_SESSION['admin_user']) or isset($_SESSION['normal_user'])){

        if( $_SESSION['admin_user'] !== 'admin_user' ){
            header('Location: somewhere.php');

        }
    }
}else{
   //meaning user is not logged or session had terminated 
   header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: where do i need to place $admin_user = $_SESSION['admin_user'] ;
$normal_user = $_SESSION['normal_user'] ; ? is it for replacement for $_SESSION['admin_user'] = $admin_user ;
$_SESSION['normal_user'] = $normal_user  ;?

Comment: hi in your login.php where you login the user

example : 
if( password_verify($password,$db_password) ){
 // verify password , assuming you are using password_hash() function
$_SESSION['admin_user']   =  $user_role ;
$_SESSION['normal_user']   =  $user_role  
                
                redirect('dashboard.php');
            }else{
                error_message('your password is incorrect');
                return false;
            }

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to implement role-based access control on your website.

Here is a possible implementation using prepared statements:

```
<?php

// db.php should create a mysqli insance:
// $con = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "databaseName"); 
require('db.php');
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    //Checking is user existing in the database or not
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users_detail WHERE username = ? and password = ?";

    //use prepared statement
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows !== 0) {

        //fetch user from database.
        $user = $result->fetch_assoc();

        //check if user is an admin.
        if($user['account'] === "admin") {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: admin.php"); //admin's page
        }

        //check if user is a normal user.
        if($user['account'] === "user") {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: user.php"); //user's page
        }

    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert">Username/password is incorrect. Click <a href="login.php">here</a> to log-in.</div>';
    }
    //free memory used by the prepared statement.
    $stmt->close();
} else { 
    //username and password not provided.
}
?>
```

Comment: can you post the code for db.php, in my answer i'm assuming that $con is a mysqli instance. PS : show the error message if possible.

Comment: <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: login.php");
exit(); }
?>
this is my code. the code that you gave to me has no error but not redirecting to the page. 
<?

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: login.php");
exit(); }
?> and this is my session code

Comment: I tried again your code, theres no more error, it also reads my database inputs because of message errors but still, it cant direct to the said location.

Comment: this is my code
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();



if(isset($_SESSION['user_role'])){
  
    
    if(  $_SESSION['user_role'] !== 'admin'){
      
        header("Location: USERuser.php");
    }
}else{
    header("Location: index.php");
}

?>

Comment: you already accepted an answer, didn't that fix your issue ? well if you tried my answer just make sure that the page you are tying to redirect to exists in the same directory as the the above PHP file. if you need something, i'll be available in PHP chat Room.

Comment: i cant join chatroom because my reputation is only 8. huhu. i already checked the directory, but nothing happens. :(